# bit operator on int variables

Tags: c++, int, hex

I've following inputs:

```
int category;
int ID
```

ID is a number formed in this way:

```
//     CCXXXXNN
ID = 0x12345678;
```

while category is a number between 0x0 and 0xFF.

I want to check if category is equal to CC part of ID. How can I do it? I can changed category from int to uint if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either left-shift the category value you have into the appropriate position and compare just those bits with the corresponding ones in `ID`:

```
ID & 0xff000000 == category << 24  // Mask off the high bits of ID, compare with category shifted into those bits
```

or you can right-shift the category bits of `ID` and test those against the category value:

```
(ID >> 24) & 0xff == category  // Put the high bits of ID in the low bits of an int, and mask off that.
```

Personally, I would write accessor functions for the parts and use those, as it makes things more readable and flexible, and *much* less prone to error.
Errors are both easy to make and difficult to find when you're bit-twiddling, in my experience.

```
int get_category(int id) { return (id >> 24) & 0xff; }
int get_xxxx(int id)     { return (id >> 16) & 0xffff; }
int get_nn(int id)       { return id & 0xff; }

if (get_category(ID) == category && get_nn(ID) < 57)
    // and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

`ID & 0xff000000 == category << 24`

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be 24 instead of 6?

Comment: I think both answers would benefit from some additional explanation. I always find it hard to upvote an answer if it's just a bunch of code without any comment or explanation (even if the code is correct).

Answer (score 1):

```
(ID & 0xff000000) == (category << (6 * 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of implementing it is with a union:

```
int category = 12;

union u
{
    int ID;
    struct a
    {
        BYTE dummy[3];
        BYTE category;
    } b;
} ;

u temp;

if (temp.b.category == category)
{
    // ...
}
```